# NPM error on Mac OS X 10.5

Tags: node.js, macos

I've to work for a project on Mac. But i've some problems for install nodejs.
When i make node -v on the terminal it's ok but when i wan't to use the command npm that doesn't work, i've this error:

> npm -v
>   dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
>     Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
>     Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
>
> dyld: Symbol not found:
>   __ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l   Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node   Expected in:
>   /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
>
> Trace/BPT trap

So if anyone can help because i really don't know how to fix the problem...

Thank's

Comment: Looks like your Mac OS X version is not supported by the Node version that  you're using.

Comment: How did you install node? What version?

Comment: I've try with the 4.2.3 and 5.3.0, and i've the same error message... I've download the package for install node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kreepz - I recently had some machine problems, had to use an old machine, and ran into the same issues. Fear not, there is a solution!

Before we get started, please make sure you have Xcode installed on the machine. The version needed is 3.1.4 - which can be downloaded for free by registering with Apple and searching for it in Apple's dev tools [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action)

Secondly, to save us ALOT of headaches, we're going to use brew to install node. That said, OS X 10.5.x does not support homebrew, but it does support tigerbrew.

To install tigerbrew, enter the following from your command line:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew/go/install)"
```

Next, run the following to make sure brew is up to speed:

```
brew doctor
```

After running `brew doctor` you'll need to pay attention to the output closely. It's going to let you know about issues that must be resolved in your system. Address them and run `brew doctor` again until things look good.

Then, we'll need to make sure we can compile everything without hiccups. Before installing node, run the following:

```
brew install gcc48
```

Woop woop! Now what's next? You guessed it - let's install node:

```
brew install node
```

Now, that last command is going to take a while. If it fails, run `brew doctor` again and make sure all the warnings and errors are resolved. If you're still having issues, check the tigerbrew troubleshooting page [here](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew/wiki/Troubleshooting).

I hope that this helps you or anyone else looking at this! Good luck!

Comment: Up to what version of node js can you install using tigerbrew on a mac 10.5 (leopard)?